# Class written in Swift cannot be a Nib Owner (Crash)

Tags: ios, swift, nib, key-value-coding

*Here is what I am trying to do:* Design a view in a nib file. Back the view and nib owner with classes written in Swift. Instantiate nib's view in Swift. Code that crash:

```
var myViewOwner: MyViewOwner?
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: myViewOwner, options: nil) // crash
```

... with error:

> [NSObject 0x7bfa0cc0 setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key myView.

So, I have: nib file with blank view where view is of type `MyClass` and nib owner of type `MyViewOwner`. Both classes written in Swift.

### What I already tried (Initial attempt):

I will be posting only MyViewOwner class code since MyView.swift is just a class definition.

**MyViewOwner.swift**

```
class MyViewOwner {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: MyView
}
```

Caused error above.

### 2-nd attempt with NSObject:

Of course Swift objects are not KVO compliant, so I tried:

```
class MyViewOwner: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet var myView: MyView
}
```

... and:

```
class MyViewOwner: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet strong var myView: MyView = MyView() // we need to set something since it's 'strong'
}
```

Both caused error above.

### 3-rd attempt with @objc annotation:

```
@objc class MyViewOwner: NSObject {
    @objc @IBOutlet strong var myView: MyView = MyView()
}
```

Didn't helped either, same error.

What I am doing wrong? In what way should I write all code in swift to make it work?

---

**UPDATE:** Owner and View setup in xCode

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:** Owner to View connection

[image]

Comment: Is the custom class for "files owner" set correctly in the nib file?

Comment: I added screenshots with setup of Owner and View

Comment: Could you post the project at github or similar? It would be great to be able to get a look at it and experiment with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code, if it is genuinely your code, makes no sense:

```
var myViewOwner: MyViewOwner?
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: myViewOwner, options: nil)
```

The variable `myViewOwner` in the *first* line is uninitialized; there is no object there. Hence that object cannot function as the `owner:` of anything, as you ask it to do in the *second* line.

Perhaps what you mean is:

```
let myViewOwner = MyViewOwner() // or whatever the initializer is
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: myViewOwner, options: nil)
```

Comment: I'm just happy that you reproduced your code accurately in your question. I was so amazed at that code, I was afraid it was just a typo in the question itself! :) — Having said all that, you've found an excellent case where the Swift compiler is not as smart as it should be; you should probably file a bug report with Apple, complaining that the compiler should never have let that code run in the first place.

Comment: Posted at bugreport.apple.com, case number: 17738661. Open radar link: http://www.openradar.me/17738661